# One site non https

Tags: ubuntu, php, http, redirect, apache2

Hello I want to make sure that one file of my site is non https. I have this in my VirtualHost80 file

```
Redirect permanent /README.php http://<ip>/README.php
```

And I have this in my VirtualHost443 file

```
Redirect permanent / https://<ip>/
```

The whole site is https, how can I enable the one file to be non https.

Please,somebody, I have been looking at answers that haven't worked for close to a month

Comment: Why do you need this? There's no benefit, to you or your users.

Comment: I have a script that needs to scrape data off this page. I am getting the self signed cert warning page and I cannot bypass this

Comment: Trust the self-signed certificate, get a free one from Let's Encrypt, or (worst case, insecure) use cURL's `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` setting to bypass the SSL.

Comment: Can't do LetsEncrypt. I only have an ip and don't plan on putting this on a domain

Comment: OK, so take one of the other approaches I mentioned.

Comment: where would the curlopt_ssl_verifypeer go in my apache configuration

Comment: Nowhere. It'd go in the code that's doing the scraping.

Comment: which is javascript, this doesn't look like js

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Your question is tagged `PHP`. You need to explain more about what you're doing and show some code. Are you making cross-domain AJAX requests to this `README.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

Insert another condition, like  `RewriteRule  ^README.php  -  [L]`, before your RewriteCond. Or just use more conditional rewrites for HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/page1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/README.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysecurewebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work

Comment: A bit more details would be helpful. For example, this is a (perfectly working) htaccess, which would not work if put in a vhost configuration. Can you please explain what exactly you are doing and (maybe) what your apache log days. You can test your htaccess 'on the fly' here: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Answer (score 0):

ModRewrite is black magic IMO.  The quick and dirty solution is to install stunnel to do a reverse http to https connection and put it on an oddball port.  Then use the stunnel config to limit what ips can connect to just where you are scraping from (or if you can't limit ips with stunnel then setup your firewall to do it.)